# ssh config name alias not working for scp

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I have this error when using scp:

```
scp -r h1:/dir1 h2:/dir1
ssh: Could not resolve hostname online1: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

But both `ssh h1` and `ssh h2` works well for I have config name alias in .ssh/config like this:

```
Host h1
  HostName 172.16.18.xxx
  User xxx
```

No editing on /etc/hosts. And I also use `ssh-copy-id` to work out the public key. Any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you use scp with no additional options like you here, remote h1 tries to directly connect to h2.

```
h1 -> h2
```

Since `h1` need to know who `h2` is, `h1` needs the definition of `h2`. But you could also route it over your PC like

```
h1 -> your pc -> h2
```

using the **option -3**

```
scp -r -3 h1:/dir1 h2:/dir2
```

Comment: should that be "route" ?

Answer (score 1):

this will help when 'myserver' is used as alias in ssh config file

```
sudo scp -F ~/.ssh/config -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa some_local_file.zip myserver:some_remote_folder/
```